# Question related to a stalk of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is a scheme and suppose $C$ and $C'$ are two irreducible components of $X$.
Suppose also that $p \in C \cap C'$. Does is it then follow that 
$O_{X,p}$ is not an integral domain? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assuming of course $C, C'$ are distinct (which is probably what you were intending). Since the question is local, we can assume $X$ is affine (**this assumption needs to be examined**), say given by $Spec\ A$ for a ring $A$.  If $I$ is the ideal of $C$ and $J$ is the ideal of $C'$, then $I, J$ are minimal primes of $A$ contained in the prime ideal $m$ associated to $p$. Note that $(0) \subseteq I \cap J \subsetneq I$ (since $I, J$ are distinct), and so since $I$ is a minimal prime, it follows $(0)$ is not a prime ideal, so $A$ is not a domain. It follows that $(0)A_m$ is not a prime ideal of $A_m$ (if it were, then its intersection with $A$ would also be prime), and hence $A_m=\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is not a domain.

If $X$ is not affine, choose an open affine $U=Spec A$ of $X$ containing $p$. The subspace $U \cap C$ is irreducible, but as pointed out in the comments, it is not clear that it is a component of $U$, and this is crucial for the proof above.

Comment: Great proof, bravo!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does it always follow that irreducible component $C$ intersect $Spec \ A$ is an irreducible component in $Spec \ A$ ? (assuming non trivial intersection)

Comment: user201886 Good question! I'm stumped. Maybe @Georges or someone else can help, I made it community wiki.

Comment: @user201886 Yes, implicit here is the fact that if $U \subset X$ is open then $Y \mapsto Y \cap U$ gives an inclusion-preserving bijection between irreducible closed subsets in $X$ meeting $U$ and irreducible closed subests of $U$. This is just a fact about topological spaces.

Comment: The key point in all of this, by the way, is that (nonempty) open subsets of irreducible spaces are dense. You could probably prove the last statement of the answer directly using this observation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and the answer!